# angular: How to use slug names instead of hierarchical route names?

Tags: angular

**angular 4+**

Is it possible to use slug name routes instead of hierarchical route names in angular?

use this: `https://example.com/some-cool-product-name`

instead of this: `https://example.com/product/some-cool-product-name`

The first one would require using only one component in routes definition as far as I understand:

```
export const routes: Route[] = [
  {
    path: ':slugName',
    component: MyComponent,
  },
]
```

And that would be very limiting. Is there an another way? Maybe some dynamic component selection based on slugName?

**edit:**

I found this doc page https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader
and edited it to met the requirements, working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jztvhx

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Why do you think you must have `product` in the route path? Why do you want to be able to map several components to a single path? On what basis would the router choose one component over the other?

Comment: `https://example.com/some-cool-product-name` is more cumbersome to implement, because yes, this involves dynamic component compilation. Also, this improvement tends to backfire, because you pollute global url namespace with things that could be grouped under `product` path. In case you want to add non-product `foo` page at some point... nope, there's already a product with same name.